# My question got closed but I don't really understand why

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked this question a few days ago and it got closed by someone from the comment section because I apparently "left out relevant details." I disagree on the relevance of the details but that's not really important. I went ahead and added the details he felt were missing to the question because ultimately if someone responding to my question feels like details are lacking I'm more than willing to improve upon them. The reason for the closure is "off-topic" but as far as I can tell that's not the case? I guess I'm just trying to figure out what I did wrong as I've had quite a few closures on server fault when I typically have much better luck on other stack exchange websites and I'd like to understand where I'm going wrong here. [ISC Bind bind to non-local IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/1147221/isc-bind-bind-to-non-local-ip)